# Facebook APP, block api calls from other domains

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

We do have a product that utilizes the FB App to get share counts for urls.

Some of our clients have not changed their App secrets, etc, and using our own.

We would like to force them by blocking api calls from domains other than our own.

I have already added our domains to "App Domains", but FB App is still not blocking their calls and rate limiting comes into effect.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security#server-whitelist

Comment: It would be nice to add domain names instead of IPs, for websites with multiple servers.